# Programmatically adding .ics attachment entries to Google Calendar

Tags: google-apps-script

Gmail recently added a feature to add .ics attachment to your calendar by pressing a button in the email. Is there a way to do this programmatically? I looked at the Google App Script api and I didn't really find anything there.

I want to be able to process this email using a label and possibly a subject line so that calendar entries are added automatically when I send an email with an ics attachment.

Answer (score 0):

ICS is a well [defined standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2445). So, you could load up emails and [get its attachments](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getAttachments%28%29) and then auto [create events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createEvent%28String,Date,Date%29) from it.

This is very doable and would be a useful script to share with the community!

Here is a PoC [ICS parser](https://github.com/thybag/JavaScript-Ical-Parser) in JavaScript to get started.